# Crontab will not execute script

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a problem with crontab, it does not execute my shell sript.

Crontab -l :

```
01 * * * * login sh ~/delete.sh
```

Normally every minute it should execute delete.sh, but it doesn't.

Nothing in syslog:

```
Jul  8 14:00:31 crontab[22307]: (login) LIST (login)
Jul  8 14:01:08 crontab[22581]: (login) BEGIN EDIT (login)
Jul  8 14:01:51 crontab[22581]: (login) REPLACE (login)
Jul  8 14:01:51 crontab[22581]: (login) END EDIT (login)
Jul  8 14:02:01 cron[15185]: (login) RELOAD (crontabs/login)
--> THAT'S ALL.
```

PS: I've tried running it as root and as the normal user, no luck in either case.

Comment: ubuntu-14.04-server-i386

Comment: Try replacing `sh` with `/bin/sh`, crontab doesn't necessarily have all the needed paths.

Comment: The tilde (~) is not going to be expanded to your home directory.  That's a shell function.  Use the full path.

Comment: And also replace ~ with full path. .. what @lornix said ;)

Comment: 01 * * * * login /bin/sh /home/login/delete.sh   <= Doesn't work...

Comment: @NebuK One of the many helpful troubleshooting tips from the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) is this: "People frequently put 1 * * * * mycommand in crontab, wait a few minutes, and wonder why their job didn't run. In this case, it's because the timespec means one minute past every hour, rather than every minute. Try a tool like cronchecker to sanity check your timespec."

Comment: i am little confused with "login" what is this actually ?

Comment: whoami -> login ( :-s )   and the name of my server is the same... sorry :D

Comment: 1. be sure that <PATH>/delete.sh works as expected, 2. check permissions, 3. you dont need /bin/bash before script if it is executable just full path as @lornix suggested

Comment: why on earth you need hostname ?

Comment: so everything is ok after removing login i assume ? :)

Comment: IT WORKS !!!! -------------- * * * * * /bin/sh /mybin/delete.sh   --------------------

Comment: @favoretti: Cron jobs run with a limited `$PATH`, but I can just about guarantee that `/bin` is included.

Comment: @lornix: Yes, the `~` syntax (for `$HOME`) and the `~user` syntax (for `user`'s home directory) are handled by the shell. But cron uses the shell to execute commands, so you *can* use `~` in cron jobs. (I just tried it, and it works.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I used to believe that, until I stumbled on some very unorthodox UNIX distributions, after which I tend to fully qualify just about any paths used in cron lines :) Not that it will hurt anything and will always make sure that it's the stuff you want that's ran while you're away :) But I agree, on Linux it should be there.

Comment: @KeithThompson, fair enough.  I've had too many run-in's with ~ not working here, but working there... I've just got into the habit of not using it.  It can cause issues if you assume you're one user, but you're another too.  But nice to have confirmation it works in crontabs. (still reluctant to use it, look at what OP's problem was... using /etc/crontab format for a personal crontab... some things bite harder than others)  Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 5):

You're expecting this:

```
01 * * * * login sh ~/delete.sh
```

to run the command every minute. In fact, it only runs it at one minute past each hour.

Change it to this:

```
* * * * * login sh ~/delete.sh
```

To address issues raised in the comments:

Cron jobs run with a limited `$PATH`, but `/bin` is certain to be in that `$PATH`, so there's no need to replace `sh` by `/bin/sh`.

There's no need to invoke `sh` explicitly. Just make sure that `~/delete.sh` has a proper [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`) and that it's executable (`chmod +x ~/delete.sh`), and you can invoke it directly.

I don't know why you have a `login` command. It doesn't make sense to try to log in from a cron job. In any case, `login` doesn't take a command as an argument.

If `login` is meant to be a user name rather than a command, keep in mind that there are two different syntaxes for crontab entries. In the normal syntax, each line consists of 5 fields specifying when the job runs, followed by the command and its arguments. A *system* crontab entry adds a user account name between the time specification and the command. [`man 5 crontab`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) for details. In normal usage, you should use the normal user syntax and manage your crontab using the `crontab` command; don't edit `/etc/crontab` or files under `/etc/cron.*` unless you absolutely have to.